# Convert java.security "NONEwithRSA" signature into BouncyCastle lightweight API

Tags: java, cryptography, rsa, bouncycastle

I need to convert Java app into C# and therefore need to migrate from java.security API into `BouncyCastle` lightweight API.

My working code (java.security) looks like this:

```
private byte[] computeSignature(byte[] message, PrivateKey key) {
    Signature signature = Signature.getInstance("NONEwithRSA");
    signature.initSign(privateKey);
    signature.update(message);
    return signature.sign();
}
```

This is my verification:

```
private void verifySignature(byte[] signature, byte[] message, PublicKey publicKey) {
    Signature signature = Signature.getInstance("NONEwithRSA");
    signature.initVerify(publicKey);
    signature.update(message);
    System.out.println(signer.verify(result) ? "OK" : "FAIL");
}
```

Now I am trying to migrate it to BC like this:

1. problem with `NONEwithRSA` algorithm which doesn't exist (not sure how to add it)

   ```
   private byte[] computeSignature(byte[] message, AsymmetricKeyParameter key) {
       AlgorithmIdentifier sigAlgId = new DefaultSignatureAlgorithmIdentifierFinder().find("NONEwithRSA");
       AlgorithmIdentifier digAlgId = new DefaultDigestAlgorithmIdentifierFinder().find(sigAlgId);
       ContentSigner signer = new BcRSAContentSignerBuilder(sigAlgId, digAlgId).build(key);
       signer.getOutputStream().write(Arrays.copyOf(message, message.length), 0, message.length);
       byte[] signature = signer.getSignature();
   }
   ```
2. doesn't provide good signature

   ```
   private byte[] computeSignature(byte[] message, AsymmetricKeyParameter privateKey) {
       Signer signer = new GenericSigner(new RSAEngine(), new NullDigest());
       signer.init(true, privateKey);
       signer.update(message, 0, message.length);
       return signer.generateSignature();
   }
   ```

Do you have any suggestions? Or is it even possible to migrate the `NONEwithRSA` algorithm into BC LW API? I assume that I need to write my own Signer, but as a newb to BC and with the BC documentation I can't handle this on my own.

Comment: Hi leizeQ, please use often used tags (with many followers). At least try and include the programming language. [tag:lightweight] does honor its name: it has 2 followers, and it does not just target bouncy castle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
RSABlindedEngine engine = new RSABlindedEngine();
PKCS1Encoding paddedEngine = new PKCS1Encoding(engine);
paddedEngine.init(true, privateKey);
return paddedEngine.processBlock(message, 0, message.length);
```