# BouncyCastle NONEwithRSA signature algorithm

Tags: hash, rsa, bouncycastle, sign, sha

I was changing Security Provider in Java to BouncyCastle Provider and now I have an exception that signature algorithm `NONEwithRSA` does not exists in BouncyCastle Provider.

I am using it through `JcaContentSignerBuilder`.

Is there any reason why there is no such algorithm and is there any way how to handle it using BouncyCastle Provider? I am providing hash functions externally and I need to only use RSA on it.

Comment: Seems to be answered in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21876156/convert-java-security-nonewithrsa-signature-into-bouncycastle-lightweight-api#21923085

Comment: I can't use proposed answer because I'm not able to chanhe the source code, only Security Provider in Java.

Comment: See https://bouncycastle.org/specifications.html `NONEwithRSA` is not supported

Comment: Why do you want to use a specific security provider that *doesn't* support your algorithm?

Comment: I need to use BouncyCastle due to internal policies. But I see that it wouldn't be so easy when the algorithm is not supported.

Comment: A stack trace would help. Also what version of BC are you using?